# How do I write ultimate equality in mathjax?

Tags: support, mathjax

[image]

The above symbol is referred to as ultimate equality in Tristan Needham's Visual Differential Geometry. How do I write it in latex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\asymp` to get $\asymp$ (for "is asymptotic to").

Answer (score 5):

A good resource is [DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html); you can draw the symbol you want and it will provide possible $\LaTeX$ codes for it. Note, however, that MathJax does not support all packages, so some of the options may not be available.

For this picture, it suggests `\asymp`, $\asymp$ as noted by Peter Phipps, which is regular $\LaTeX$ and so supported.